# override textFieldShouldEndEditing when cancel button pressed

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitextfield

I have a detailview with a number of fields, some of which use textFieldShouldEndEditing to do some validation. This all works well. However, if a user enters invalid data in a field and then pushes the cancel button, the validation routine still runs as textFieldShouldEndEditing is getting called. Is there a way to prevent this? In other words just get a clean cancel as I dont care what the field contains.

Comment: can you please, place your code here in detail so we can get it what you mean !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside the cancel button function 
clear your current textfield.text=@"";

check textFieldShouldEndEditing initially

```
if  ([textfield.text isEqualtoEmpty:@""] 
{
return Yes;
}
else{

// check your condition here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Senthikumar's answer works in that particular case, but I had a similar case in which I needed to check that the field was also not empty ...

Therefore I used the following technique :

1. I created a BOOL property called "cancelButtonPressed"
2. In the method linked to the cancel button, I set this BOOL to YES
3. In **textViewShouldEndEditing**, I first check this BOOL. If it is NO, I do my controls (including alert views for example). This method should always finish by calling **return YES;**, meaning that if this "cancelButtonPressed" BOOL was YES, it should end the textfield editing (and not throw an alert at my face for instance).

In addition (this is not directly linked to the question, but it usually comes with the "cancel" function), you may also have a "**save**" button, in which case you want to prevent the user to save if you are editing a textField and the entry is not correct.
In that case, I create another BOOL called "textFieldInError", and set it to YES if my controls in 
textViewShouldEndEditing fails, and to NO if my controls succeed (at the end of the method).
Then, in the method linked to my save button, I check that this BOOL is NO.

Here is the complete code :

```
  @property (nonatomic) BOOL cancelButtonPressed;
  @property (nonatomic) BOOL textFieldInError;


  - (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {
    // If the user pressed Cancel, then return without checking the content of the textfield
    if (!self.cancelButtonPressed) {

       // Do your controls here
       if (check fails) {
            UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                         message:@"Incorrect entry"
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [av show];

            // Prevent from saving
            self.textFieldInError = YES;

            return NO;
       }
    }

    // Allow saving
    self.textFieldInError = NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Save & cancel methods :

```
- (void)saveButtonPressed;
{
   // Resign first responder, which removes the decimal keypad
   [self.view endEditing:YES];

   // The current edited textField must not be in error
   if (!self.textFieldInError) {
      // Do what you have to do when saving
   }
}

- (void)cancel;
{
    self.cancelButtonPressed = YES;

    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I hope that can help other people, because I had a big headache solving this in a clean, straightforward way.

Fred

Comment: Thank you Fred, you helped me so that is at least one person. Nice easy solution.